# How to add keys in android dropdown list

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I need to pass `country` codes to server, and display complete country name to user.

e.g: `USA` for server, and `United State of America` for display.

This is what i am using now.

```
<string-array name="countries_array">
        <item>United State of America</item>
</string-array>
```

but now i need to display `country full name` but pass its `code` to server.

This is what i do to get the selected value.

```
spinnerCountry.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                               int position, long id) {
        country = spinnerCountry.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

Comment: what do you want exactly??

Comment: @YoLo : need to get code of country while displaying country full name to user. So user will be seeing `United state of America`, but user tap on it, i will get `USA` value from it.

Answer (score 1):

It's OOPS.
You use class having country code and full name, then use its list to get coutry's full name by country code, selected by user.

**Or**

Have two different arrays of same size and order of country codes and their full names.

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need to write all Country Name and Country Code. You can get them from Android Locale. Try with below code.

```
  String[] isoCountryCodes = Locale.getISOCountries();
        ArrayList<Country> countryArrayList = new ArrayList<Country>();

        for (String code : isoCountryCodes) {
            Locale locale = new Locale("", code);
            String name = locale.getDisplayCountry();
            countryArrayList.add(new Country(name, code));
        }
        //Sort Country List
        Collections.sort(countryArrayList, new Comparator<Country>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Country c1, Country c2) {
                return c1.countryName.compareTo(c2.countryName);
            }
        });

        Spinner spinnerCountry = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerCountry);
        ArrayAdapter<Country> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Country>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, countryArrayList);
        spinnerCountry.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        spinnerCountry.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                String countryCode = countryArrayList.get(i).countryCode;
                Toast.makeText(TestActivity.this, countryCode, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });
```

And Create Country class as follow

```
class Country {
    String countryName;
    String countryCode;

    public Country(String countryName, String countryCode) {
        this.countryName = countryName;
        this.countryCode = countryCode;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return countryName ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [country-picker-android](https://github.com/mukeshsolanki/country-picker-android)

You have the flags icons / full country name referenced by ISO country code and you can get the ISO code of the country on user selection.